# how exclude javafx dependencies from jar created with maven assembly?

Tags: java, maven, javafx

My program creates two different jar through maven: one is the server app, the other is the GUI application.
I wanted to put JavaFX inside the app, so who runs it can run it without installing JavaFX.
The problem is that now even the Server Jar has inside it JavaFX, which is useless of course.
How I can remove it?

In my POM file the dependecies are: `maven-compiler-plugin`, `maven-assembly-plugin`, `javafx-graphics`, `javafx-controls`, `javafx-fxml`, `junit`.
I built it reading a guide, following this model for all the 2 apps:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>single</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <archive>
            <manifest>
                <mainClass>
                    com.baeldung.executable.ExecutableMavenJar
                </mainClass>
            </manifest>
            </archive>
            <descriptorRefs>
                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
            </descriptorRefs>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

Comment: Hmm. Did you place each project into separate, independent sub-modules? If so, then the JavaFX dependencies should only be declared for the client module.